# Does bagged lettuce need a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, bugs, vegetables, leniencies

Does one need a hechsher on commercially available bagged lettuce? Or is the standard washing process used by the producers sufficient to remove all insects of halachic significance?

Anecdotally, I've noticed that a few Chabad Houses I am familiar with use bagged lettuce without a hechsher and do not check it themselves. When asked, they told me that their custom was not to be "machmir" about the issue of bugs. I assume that means they rely on the view of the Aruch HaShulchan YD 100:13 who provides a limmud zechus for "all the masses of Jews who are not careful (to check) and eat anything that comes into their hands as long as they don't see any obvious infestation, and Heaven forfend to say that all the Jews are stumbling in a great sin like this"

Are there sources for the leniency to rely specifically on commercial washing without a sampling-based hechsher? Or is the Aruch haShulchan really the primary basis for leniency? Are there contemporary poskim who are lenient?

Comment: When does the Aruch Hashulchan apply? I've heard that when an infestation is found, its pretty obvious- but they're only found in certain harvests. Does that mean that lettuce overall has no obvious infestation?

Comment: Also make sure to separate Terumot and Maasrot as necessary if there is no Hechsher.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/what-is-better-checking-yourself-or-buying-pre-checked

Comment: of interest: http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-BugsRevisited.htm <-- background halachot and explanation of how the Star-K certifies lettuce

Comment: some more useful links:  [1]: http://www.oukosher.org/images/uploads/OU_Guide_to_Fruits__Veg.pdf
 [2]: http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/ou_announces_new_edition_of_ou_guide_to_checking_fruits_vegetables_and_berr/
 [3]: http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/learn/fruits_vegetables

Comment: As far as I know, the leniency is primarily based on the view that a Beriah is ossur Miderabannan (which the Aruch Hashulchan mentions, IIRC). Once you say that many more leniencies open up. The general Machmir stance is based on 1) it being Medioraisa and 2) a Miut HaMatzui being any situation where you won't be taken by surprise to find it. In Chabad there is no agreement among the various respected Rabbanim on either issue, but I'm sure the Chabad Houses you are familiar with are following the more lenient view.

Comment: @Yishai Biryah being assur miderabanan is definitely the majority view in Rishonim and Achronim.

Comment: @Curiouser It is true that Chabad is to some extent lenient on some aspects bug checking--for example, many Chabadniks are OK with strawberries and AFAIK do not even check them--but I'm stunned that you've found "a few" or even one Chabad House that doesn't check bagged lettuce without a hechsher.  While it seems that some people don't check this, it is really mainstream to do so, and not just by the ultra-Orthodox. I'm puzzled by this, frankly...

Answer (score 4):

According to the [cRc of Chicago](http://www.crcweb.org/fruit%20&%20veg%20guide.php), **iceberg** lettuce that is prewashed may be used without hashgacha and without any further washing.

But the cRc [adds](https://twitter.com/cRcKosher/status/837676161224278016):  "It ... still ... can (and must) be checked with a chazaka check."

Comment: What about further checking??

Comment: It looks like further checking is required.  The cRc [adds](https://twitter.com/cRcKosher/status/837676161224278016):  "It ... still ... can (and must) be checked with a chazaka check."