# Do you have to check bagged lettuce with a hechsher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, bugs

I am aware of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17165/does-bagged-lettuce-need-a-hechsher) and of [the CRC's lenient policy](http://www.crcweb.org/Lettuce_policy_revised.pdf) on lettuce without a hechsher. However, everywhere I've been, it is assumed that one needs to check (pre-washed, even triple-washed) bagged lettuce if it doesn't have a hechsher on the bag. I proceed on the assumption that it is the minhag, if not the halacha, to do so.

My question is instead about pre-checked lettuce with a hechsher on the bag, which one can sometimes find, even from mainstream brands and in regular stores. Strictly speaking, does one need wash and/or check this before use? A few points:

- My kosher grocery store carried a sign saying something like "Bagged lettuce without a hechsher on the bag must be checked" (perhaps implying, perhaps correctly that bagged lettuce *with* a hechsher doesn't need to be checked).
- However, a friend of mine who knows her way around a kosher kitchen suggested to me that even bagged lettuce with a hechsher should be checked (although she didn't seem particularly sure or emphatic about it).
- There is also the consideration of whether lettuce needs to be checked [in principle](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71646/1516), even if only by cursory inspection.

Can anyone bring sources to answer this question definitively? Does commercially available bagged lettuce with a reliable hechsher need to be personally checked before it can be used?

Comment: Often the lettuce that you supposedly don't need to check is full if insecticide. Personally I check all my lettuce,, hechsher or not,, and believe it may be a mitzvah to do so (albeit one on which you don't say a b'racha).

Answer (score 3):

The OU and cRc have the policy that bagged, washed **iceberg lettuce** is almost never a bug issue. Therefore, a bagged **iceberg** (or iceberg/cabbage/carrot) mix with a hechsher needs no further checking.

(Iceberg forms a very tight head, which is harder for bugs to penetrate. As the OU's Rabbi Genack said, "why do people prefer romaine lettuce? Brighter color, more vitamins, stronger flavor -- well, the bugs like it more for the same reasons!")

For **romaine** ... it depends what degree of non-bug certainty you require, and whose hechsher it is. A Star-K or OU on the bag means that statistically, this washing process has been found to reduce the odds of a bug to under 10%, which most poskim consider good enough. (Now is that odds of one bug per serving or per bag ... depends who you ask once again!) In their opinion, a bag with such a hechsher is ready to eat. (Though if you happen to see a bug, don't eat it!)

More right-wing hashgachos would want a probability far less than 9.9%, and assurances stronger than statistics on the process (e.g. human checkers).

I contacted a different lettuce machshir that basically said "it's triple washed so it should be fine"; the Star-K or OU would probably want additional checking in that situation.

Comment: If you can place some links to any articles listing these findings, please do so. Reading "between the lines", I think these organizations require a much stricter checking process for restaurants than they do for home use, even if both places use the same product. 2 Ortho. rabannim I know who are heads of a Va'ad told me that the Torah does not require one to use an X-RAY light or magnifying glass to find bugs in any produce.

Comment: @Shalom I'm surprised that OU and especially the CRC would allow eating an iceberg/cabbage/carrot mix without a hechsher. Do they consider that pre-shredded carrots don't need a hechsher? Certainly not everyone does